# SQL Server Data Tools-BI for Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, business-intelligence, bids

I've installed *Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop*. Can I install *Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012*?

I have Windows 7 Pro x64 and SQL Server 2008 RTM (build 10.0.1600.22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express versions of Visual Studio are free.

And you get what you pay for - none of them can be extended, at all.

Comment: Thanks, I know they're free. I assumed as much, but just wanted to double-check.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand the answer. Do we need to have license or not?

Comment: A license wouldn't help. The express editions cannot be extended.